# I want to show/hide Angular 6 reactive form group based on checkbox selection

Tags: angular6

I have a form-group which I want to show/hide based on a checkbox selection in reactive form. I am using Angular 6. Can someone please guide to article or an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngIF to condition of show your form;

```
<div class="button-row" *ngIf="checkbox.value"> <===this is condit. true/false
  <button md-raised-button>Basic</button>
  <button md-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
  <button md-raised-button color="accent">Accent</button>
  <button md-raised-button color="warn">Warn</button>
  <button md-raised-button disabled>Disabled</button>
  <a md-raised-button routerLink=".">Link</a>
</div>

<md-checkbox  [formControl]="checkbox">Checked</md-checkbox>
```

Than in controller you define form control :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  checkbox = new FormControl(false);
}
```

For default checkbox is false, but you can change it  `checkbox = new FormControl(false/true);`

You can find here my solution  [Fast example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-b219jr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)